# An error occurred saving the transfer queue

Tags: filezilla

I'm using macOS M1 and I'm having this problem after updating Filezilla:

> An error occurred saving the transfer queue to
> /Users/pradeep/.config/filezilla/queue.sqlite3. Some queue items might
> not have been saved.

I think there is a file path problem.

Comment: It is caused by some kind of incompatibility issue. I happened to me only after updating FileZilla to latest version. I removed queue.sqlite3 from C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming\FileZilla and it was done. FileZilla will auto create this file on next startup. On other OS, you need to check user date folder where such files are stored.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I removed manually the queue.sqlite3 file and the error disappeared.

In your case:

```
rm /Users/pradeep/.config/filezilla/queue.sqlite3
```

Comment: beautiful, thank you, i just had the same issue and found this :-)